# googletrans getting output same with input when translate

Tags: translation, google-translate, translate

I got a problem with google trans I have to write the code for translation but when I run it shows the output same with the input I have tried this problem around 3-4 hour but can not be solved it
guys please give me the answer and give me the suggestion

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
result = translator.translate('안녕하세요.',dest='en')
print(result.text)
```

And gives me output like 안녕하세요. it was the same with the input I give
so guys please help I need your help
thank you very kind of you

Comment: Google translate returns the input string when it doesn't know the translation. Try with something very simply first.

Comment: yes sir it show the same thing when i do this `result = translator.translate('Hello',dest='fr')`  and the output also print Hello